# Mysql query with order by. Strange execution plan

Tags: mysql, explain

I have 3 tables:

```
Product (about 700000 rows)
ProductId int(11) AI PK 
ManufacturerId int(11) FK
Name varchar(256) 
Description text 
SKU varchar(64) 
Code varchar(64) 
ArtId int(11) 
StockStateId int(2) FK
Quantity int(11) 
QuantityText varchar(61) 
Price decimal(12,2) 
CurrencyId int(2) 
AutoImport bit(1) 
ImpactOnBalance bit(1) 
HasPhoto bit(1) 
HasParams bit(1)

StockState (3 rows)
StockStateId int(2) AI PK 
Name varchar(64)

Manufacturer (about 200 rows)
ManufacturerId int(11) AI PK 
Name varchar(64) 
Description text 
SortOrder int(11)
```

This is my query

```
select
     p.ProductId
    ,p.Name
    ,p.Quantity
    ,p.QuantityText
    ,m.ManufacturerId
    ,m.Name as ManufacturerName
    ,ss.StockStateId
    ,ss.Name as StockStateName
from Product p
inner join Manufacturer m on m.ManufacturerId = p.ManufacturerId
inner join StockState ss on ss.StockStateId = p.StockStateId
order by p.ProductId asc
limit 1000, 25
```

I cannot understand why mysql doesn't use right indexes (it takes ~10s to get result). Execution plan looks like this
[first query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmEzA.png).
I can force mysql to use primary index

```
from Product p force index (primary)
```

It'll increase performance to 0.015s, but I'm going to use this query in SP where order depends on input parameter. So I've added dummy case condition

```
set @order = '';
select
     p.ProductId
    ,p.Name
    ,p.Quantity
    ,p.QuantityText
    ,m.ManufacturerId
    ,m.Name as ManufacturerName
    ,ss.StockStateId
    ,ss.Name as StockStateName
    from Product p force index (primary)
inner join Manufacturer m on m.ManufacturerId = p.ManufacturerId
inner join StockState ss on ss.StockStateId = p.StockStateId
order by case when @order = '' then p.ProductId end asc
limit 1000, 25
```

This query should have the same execution plan like the previous one (ordering by the same column which is PK) but no, I've got filesort.
[third query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlqCD.png)

Why is this? Could someone help me to fix this? (improve query performance)r

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this, there is a left join concept, etc.

```
set @order = '';
select
     p.ProductId
    ,p.Name
    ,p.Quantity
    ,p.QuantityText
    ,m.ManufacturerId
    ,m.Name as ManufacturerName
    ,ss.StockStateId
    ,ss.Name as StockStateName
    from Product p force index (primary)
//this line what I mean 
inner join Manufacturer m on p.ManufacturerId = m.ManufacturerId
//also this line what I mean
inner join StockState ss on p.StockStateId = ss.StockStateId
order by case when @order = '' then p.ProductId end asc
limit 1000, 25
```

Because you must check row in your Product first, then join to Manufacturer

if you check Manufacturer first, it will problem if row in Manufacturer not exist in Product (wasting time)